# Efficiently structuring large React.js applications with multiple views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a react application with multiple views (e.g. `Profile`, `Followers`).  Each of those views currently lives as it's own React component that executes on both server side and client side.  I'm starting to struggle understanding the proper way to structure the code.

For example, let's say `Profile` is loaded and the user clicks on "See Followers".  At that point, the dispatcher is sent a message that says `gotoFollowers`.  At the top level, we then render a whole new React component (i.e. the `Followers` component).  Unfortunately, both the `Follower` and `Profile` components requires similar data (e.g. Session data, userphoto, username, and even followers too, because we show a snippet of followers on the `Profile`).  So, it feels very wasteful to have to re-render at the top-level (including doing ajax calls) every time the user changes the page.

I assume I'm not doing this correctly.  Should I be using a single parent React component? (I see issues with that too) How am I supposed to structure large React applications with many views?

```
window.render = function (page, id, pushState) {
  var stateURL = '';

  switch (page) {
    case 'Profile':
      stateURL = '/' + id;
      async.parallel({
        profileData: function (callback) { MemberLoader.load(id, callback); },
        followerData: function (callback) { FollowerLoader.load(id, callback); },
        },
        sessionData: function (callback) { Session.get(callback); },
      }, function (err, results) {
        var component = React.createFactory(Profile);
        React.render(component({ member: results.profileData, followers: results.followerData, session: results.sessionData }), mountNode);
      });
      break;
    case 'Followers':
      stateURL = '/' + id + '/followers';
      async.parallel({
        profileData: function (callback) { MemberLoader.load(id, callback); },
        sessionData: function (callback) { Session.get(callback); },
        followerData: function (callback) { FollowerLoader.load(id, callback); },
      }, function (err, results) {
        var component = React.createFactory(Followers);
        React.render(component({ member: results.profileData, followers: results.followerData, session: results.sessionData  }), mountNode);
      });
      break;
  };

  if (pushState) {
    window.history.pushState({ page: page, id: id }, null, stateURL);
  } else {
    window.history.replaceState({ page: page, id: id }, null, stateURL);
  }

};

Dispatcher.register(function(event) {
  if (event.action === 'gotoProfile') {
    window.render('Profile', event.username, true);
  } 
  else if (event.action === 'gotoFollowers') {
    window.render('Followers', event.username, false); 
  }
});
```

**Note**: Our application renders on both server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of fetching the same data multiple times, you should look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)- this could replace the `async` lib you are using right now.

Promises allow you to make an asynchronous call once, but attach callbacks even after the call has been made successfully. You can maintain a reference to the promise and use it later on in your application- without having to check whether or not the promise has already been resolved or not.

I put together an (untested) example implementation for you below- it does a couple things.

1. Creates references to promises for each of your data stores
2. Creates a method that returns makes the async call if it hasn't already been made, and then returns that promise
3. Replace your `async.parallel` code with `Promise.all`, which creates a new promise that is resolved when all the passed promises have been resolved successfully.
4. Put your `React.render` inside a call to `then` on the promise- that way it is only called when all the async calls have finished.

See below:

```
var profilePromise;
var followerPromise;
var sessionPromise;    

var getProfilePromise = function(){
  //If the profile promise already exists (ie, the async call has already been started)
  //then we return the promise, otherwise we make the async call.
  if(!profilePromise){
    profilePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      MemberLoader.load(id, function(){
        //Depending on the result you either call `resolve` and pass
        //in the data, or call `reject` with the error
      });
    });    
  }    

  return profilePromise;
};
//Repeat a version of the above function for your follower and session promise    

window.render = function (page, id, pushState) {
  var stateURL = '';    

  switch (page) {
    case 'Profile':
      stateURL = '/' + id;
      Promise.all([
        getProfilePromise(),
        getFollowerPromise(),
        getSessionPromise()
      ]).then(function(results){
        var component = React.createFactory(Profile);
        React.render(component({ member: results[0], followers: results[1], session: results[2] }), mountNode);
      }).catch(function(err){
        /** handle errors here */
      });
      break;
    case 'Followers':
      stateURL = '/' + id + '/followers';
      Promise.all([
        getProfilePromise(),
        getFollowerPromise(),
        getSessionPromise()
      ]).then(function(results) {
        var component = React.createFactory(Followers);
        React.render(component({ member: results[0], followers: results[1], session: results[2]  }), mountNode);
      }).catch(function(err){
        /** handle errors here */
      });
      break;
  }    

  if (pushState) {
    window.history.pushState({ page: page, id: id }, null, stateURL);
  } else {
    window.history.replaceState({ page: page, id: id }, null, stateURL);
  }    

};
```